# count occurrences of test in string php, not test123 or testabc

Tags: php, count

i used code:

```
$text = 'This is test22 is a test11 abc test mlk'
result= substr_count($text, 'test',0,0)
```

`result = 3;`

but my desired output = `1`;

i just want to count the number of occurrences of the exact word `test`, not `testaaa` or `test123`

Thank you

Comment: If I correct a few basic errors in your code and test it, I get zero: https://3v4l.org/mn8Rl Please test your code before you put it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string check alone can't do this. I would use a regex for this. Using word boundaries and `preg_match` this can be done with:

```
$text = 'This is test22 is a test11 abc test mlk';
preg_match('/\btest\b/', $text, $result);
echo count($result);
```

Alternatively `preg_replace` could be used which has a `count` feature built into it.

```
preg_replace('/\btest\b/', '', $text, -1, $count);
```

Comment: Very nice info about `preg_replace()`...I was going to compare the original length against the length with all `test` removed, but we don't even need to do that `:-)`